# CSGO: Overview of Weapon Cases

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

Is there an overview of every weapon case which has ever existed?

I found lots of sites on google, which deal with weapon skins, but I found not a single overseeable list of every weapon case.

Comment: What, exactly, are you looking for?  What is the purpose of finding this information?

Comment: The purpose is that I have a list in order to compare prizes more easily. A list which I can process down for finding prices out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the CS:GO stash, here is a link to the cases page: 
[CS:GO CASES](http://csgostash.com/containers)

Comment: Thats what I searched. Very nice